# Simplifying a complex method

Tags: c++, c, simplify

I have a method which is basically a long list of `if`-`else`'s with variable depth (sometime pretty deep) since it is interpreting an array of bytes and depending on each byte's value it does something different, such as "reading" more from the array and again checking them for some values, or it has a direct action. Something like this:

```
char current = array[current_index ++];
if(current == 1)
{
    char something = array[current_index ++];
    if(something == 2)
    {
         // open the fridge
    }
    else
    {
         char something_else = array[current_index ++];
         if(something_else == 3)
         {
             // make me a cake
         }
         else
         {
             // bring me a beer
         }
    }
}
else
if(current == check_this(another_variable))
{
     // so something else
}
```

I am trying to simplify this entire mess. So, to get rid of the first level of `if`s I have created an array of function pointers, extracted the `if`'s bodies into the specific functions and basically see if the array has an element for the given `current` and execute the function (as a side effect this has slightly reduced the execution speed and largely reduced the readability).

A short example

a list of commands:

1 - food
2 - drink
3 - go home
4 - warm
5 - cold
6 - meat
7 - tomato

so: `1 4 6` - will get me grilled meat (or at least according to the application's implementation)
and `2 7`   - will give me tomato juice...
and `3`     - exit.

**Edit:** The `switch` - `case` construct is not always usable in this scenario since sometimes `current` is checked against to a return value of a function.

So the question: I am curios what other techniques would you use for attacking this kind of problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to codereview.SE

Comment: `array[current_index] ++`? Or should it be `array[current_index++]`?

Comment: @Shahbaz :) array[current_index++] definitely... Thanks, corrected!

Comment: @devnull please see the edit. Sometimes the switch-case is not applicable since there also checks against function return values

Comment: I don't know the problem so this comment will be probably a spam one, but have you considered recursion?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing the actual problem you're solving. Considering the fact that you're checking characters in an array (or string), you probably want recursion or a FSM.

Comment: **clean code**. Basiscally you could keep your flow as it is right now , just make sure that your depth deos not exceed 2nd level in which case you have to extract code to some other method.

Comment: Your problem, as stated, has some complexities: the action to take does not depend only on the value in the array but also on the position the value takes. Is that correct? Is there a semantics/relationship related to each array position? in other words, if I understand correctly: 1 4 6 wouldn't generate the same input than 1 6 or 4 1 6.

Comment: @Picarus You're right: 1 6 would give you raw meat, while 4 1 6 would not be defined for this context. So, there is always an action (1 2 or 3) followed by one or more specifiers (4 5) and then there's is the object of the action (6 7). Obviously this example is very simplified :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something similar to `Command` pattern. Create a dictionary where keys will be possible values of elements in `array` and values will be pointers to corresponding functions, something like:

```
{
1 = (*open_the_fridge),
2 = (*make_me_a_cake),
...
}
```

Then you can loop over `array` and execute corresponding functions.

Pseudocode:

```
func_map{1=(*open_the_fridge), 2=(*make_me_a_cake),...}
for (i = 0; i < length(array); i++) {
    (*get_value_from_dict(func_map, array[i]))();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like decision tree - you can initialize this tree with all possible combination with results and then write one cycle which searches input combination and returns result. Result can be a string or Command (as suggested in other answer)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer to comments I think you should change your "paradigm" and transform your array structure to a tuple or object with meaningful attributes.
The point is that it looks like not all "execution paths" will require the same number of parameters but OO encapsulation should help you to deal with that.
So, you must solve the problem at origin, where the array is generated.
If this is not possible because it is a library or code that you cannot modify for whatever reason you should write an adapter so that you can handle things properly.

Then, you specify in your question C and C++ tags. Depending on the approach you want to take the community could provide more detail on specific solutions.

A Factory (or factory like) pattern can help you to create the appropriate objects or tuples.
A more simple approach could be to change the signature of your method to take 3 parameters: action, parameters, object type as you have specified.